# Confused: context.getExternalFilesDir vs. Environment.getExternalStorageState();

Tags: android, file-permissions, file-handling

I'm developing with Android Studio on various emulated devices.

```
Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())
```

always returned false UNTIL I chose to emulate SD cards on the emulated devices.

But the documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html specifically states that

> "there are always two storage spaces and the API behavior is the same whether the external storage is removable or not."

This seems to indicate that external storage need not refer to an actual SD card and could be internal. Therefore, why would I need to size the emulated SD card greater than zero to get that code to work? What am I misunderstanding or missing?

Also, does context.getExternalFilesDir refer to the same directory's flags as Environment.getExternalStorageState?

Thank you,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose emulate SD cards to indicate the emulator that you have an external storage associated. And what you said is correct, an external storage can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage.

Yes, context.getExternalFilesDir returns the absolute path to the directory on the external filesystem as per the documentation, hence refers to the same directory's flags as Environment.getExternalStorageState

Comment: It sounds like I cannot count on external storage *always* being available. For instance, if someone mounted then removed an SD card, the OS is not going to have some built-in storage available as external storage.

Is there *always* some "external" storage available, even in the case of no SD card, or a removed SD card?

Thanks again -

Comment: @Pradeep, I'm running this on a physical device.  Trying to code logic to tell if the external SD card is available for download of files to or if it needs to switch to internal.  I thought the getExternalStorageState could be used to determine if the external SD card was present or not.  What am I missing?